# How to disable plug in sound on late 2016 macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I found it once and not again, but there is a way to kill that horrible chime when you plug in the mbp.  (It reset itself upon a reboot, but it's the best I could do.)
  Now I can't find that language.
  I'm not talking about the boot up chime, but rather that stupid cell phone charge plug in noise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool false; killall PowerChime
```

It resets upon boot up but this will do it temporarily.  I'd love to find out how to disable this permanently.

EDIT: I am so proud of myself.  Here is what a dummy can learn to do for himself.  After I found that code for Terminal above, I had to figure out how to make that command run upon login.

Open TextEdit and type

```
#!/bin/bash

defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool false; killall PowerChime

exit 0
```

... and save it on the desktop as "PCK.txt."  (Powerchime killer)

Rename that file to "PCK.ps"

Open up Terminal and enter

```
cd ~/desktop
```

to navigate to the desktop, where the PCK file is.  Then type

```
chmod +x PCK.ps
```

Now you can test the script if you want, hopefully it works and the sound is killed!

Next, under the Terminal drop down menu, there are preferences.  Under the Profiles tab there is a Shell "sub tab" on the right.  In this tab there is a "When the shell exits" section, under which is a box that you can choose one of three options.  I chose "Close if the shell exited cleanly," and now when I double click my "PCK.ps" file, a Terminal window flashes and that stupid powerchime is dead.

The final step is to add PCK.ps to my specific user login items.  The login items are located in Preferences / Users and Groups / >user of choice< / Login Items.  Then, click the plus sign and browse to PCK.ps and add it.  Check the box and now try a reboot!

Comment: The only slight bummer about this is that the Terminal program still needs to be closed manually.  This is about the only thing I use Terminal for regularly so it'd be great if I could get this shell command to QUIT Terminal after exiting the script!

Comment: Looks like you're looking for this strategy, this will run silently and not leave terminal open - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372744/228369

Answer (score 8):

Since updating to OS High Sierra this no longer works!  But a much smarter person than me posted a much better solution: [Turning Power Chime Off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282752/turning-power-chime-off)

Comment: Okay this work 99% of the time.  The remaining 1% is upon waking the laptop, before the screen turns on, but after I open it, if I plug the power cord in during this "black screen" moment, it chimes!  I have NO IDEA how it finds the sound, since I muted the powerchime.aif file.  Kinda scary.