# Turning Power Chime Off

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, power

On new Macbook Pro, Power Chime runs. Whenever I delete from core services it comes right back. It makes a sound when plugging in your power cord even when the volume is at 0%.

The solution I have now to disable this annoying sound is an AppleScript application that runs on login to kill the process via terminal. Is there a better way?

Comment: What's your address? I'll send you something. LOL Oh wait, maybe I should send it to Tetsujin? :)

Comment: unfortunately idont think his solution works.

Comment: Has anyone tried to just delete the power chime app in the system files folder?

Comment: OP, you should accept the answer below: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309947/190701

Comment: @Jake sudo rm: /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/MacOS/PowerChime: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The solution is to set `ChimeOnNoHardware` to `true` instead of setting `ChimeOnAllHardware` to `false` (note, `No` instead of `All`):

```
defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnNoHardware -bool true
killall PowerChime
```

Comment: Thank you. This what worked for me on high sierra.

Comment: I tried this command and got this message: "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Comment: @DiscoDanny use sudo

Comment: ran this once and it works mostly, but the chime still goes off with the lid closed and the laptop locked/sleeping.

Comment: Works on Mojave, but yes the chime still goes off w/the lid closed. Also, just from testing this ~5 times I feel like the USB-C cable or port is likely to break in short order. Port is too tight & the cable is as flimsy as they always are from Apple. RIP Magsafe...

Comment: Ditto @mc01 -- on Mojave the chime still goes off when the lid is closed. Does anyone have an updated solution?

Comment: > drop 'no tea'

Comment: Did NOT work for me on Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: @DiscoDanny That just means that the PowerChime task wasn't running at the time.

Comment: @Philip I have an updated solution, shown below.

Comment: @Joe Try my solution below.

Comment: Confirming that this works on catalina

Answer (score 10):

Here's another solution since the others provided don't seem to be working for you. You can create an empty AIFF file to replace the default chime. The  chime audio is located here:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
```

I created an empty AIFF file using Adobe Audition. With SIP disabled, I backed up the original chime and replaced it with my new audio file:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif_bak
sudo mv ~/Desktop/null.aif /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
```

Be sure to fix the permissions on the file:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
sudo chmod 644 /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
```

No more audio when connecting your power source.

Comment: Thanks a million this worked like a charm!  I copied the AIF to the desktop, opened the file, muted it and then saved it.  Disabled SIP and replaced it (I didn't use Terminal I just dragged and dropped), then ran those two permissions line commands and BOOM!  No more power chime.

Comment: This stopped working after updating to OS 10.13.6!  I looked at the AIF file and it is silent, so I have NO IDEA how it found that horrible sound again!  Now I'm back to square one.

Comment: Ditto @DiscoDanny.

Comment: Doesn't work with lid closed on Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this simple tool on all MacBooks after 2015 to quickly switch PowerChime

https://git.io/nochime —
runs through `curl` without installation, performs the desired job, nothing to add here.

Comment: Running a script directly from the internet (without verifying it's content first) has some risks though. Would recommend to at least install it locally and run it from there.

Comment: @nohillside good point, I agree that local installation option for the precautious would be nice to have. Though anyway, it's [open-source](https://github.com/artginzburg/powerchime/blob/main/src/powerchime.sh) and easily readable. The exact address that is `curl`ed is also easy to check: [git.io/powerchime](https://git.io/powerchime).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants my AppleScript I'm using to stop this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 3
    set ProcessList to name of every process
    if "PowerChime" is in ProcessList then
        set ThePID to unix id of process "PowerChime"
        do shell script "kill -KILL " & ThePID
    end if
end tell
```

But really looking for another way. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: checkout https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309947/190701

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous solutions worked for me. Here's how I permanently disabled the chime on a 2017 MacBook Pro running Catalina (10.15.6):

**Disable System Integrity Protection (SIP)**

1. Shut down your computer.
2. Hold down Command-R and press the power button. Keep holding them down until the Apple logo appears.
3. Wait for OS X to boot into the OS X Utilities window.
4. Choose Utilities > Terminal.
5. Enter `csrutil disable`.
6. Enter `reboot` (or otherwise reboot the computer).

[[Source](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-off-mac-os-x-system-integrity-protection-rootless-3638975/)]

**Delete the sound file**

Upon rebooting, open a terminal, and do the following:

1. Enter `csrutil status` to ensure you have disabled SIP. You should see:

```
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

2. Enter `sudo rm /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif`
3. If prompted, confirm the operation.
4. If you get an error that includes `Read-only file system`, enter `sudo mount -uw /`. This remounts the file system as read-write. Go back to step 2.

**Reenable SIP**

1. Shut down your computer.
2. Hold down Command-R and press the power button. Keep holding them down until the Apple logo appears.
3. Wait for OS X to boot into the OS X Utilities window.
4. Choose Utilities > Terminal.
5. Enter `csrutil enable`.
6. Enter `reboot` (or otherwise reboot the computer).
7. After rebooting, verify that SIP is reenabled with the terminal command `csrutil status`.

Comment: I appreciate this and tried it after seeing a similar suggestion posted elsewhere, but, to my amazement, the damn thing still chimed even though I thought I had deleted the sound of the chime (including following the disable-delete-reenable scheme). Touché, Apple...

Comment: @Philip Have you checked if `/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif` still exists?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Philip - did the whole dance:

`~$ afplay /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('wht?')`

It still chimes.   v10.15.6 (19G2021) / MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Comment: @tjmcewan That's weird. How about `ls /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif`?

Comment: Yah, sorry I wasn't clear, that file no longer exists.  Looks like that file is no longer the source of the sound.  The sound even plays when the machine is off & before I've unlocked the Filevault encryption.

Comment: @tjmcewan Any other sound files in that directory? I'd delete those.

Comment: @tjmcewan What do you mean by "the sound even plays when the machine is off"? Do you mean when the display is off or when the machine is sleeping? I had that problem too.

Comment: No other sound files. :)  I mean I literally shut down the machine.  To be super clear: Apple menu > Shut Down... > Shut Down, wait 10 seconds or so until backlight is clearly off, close the lid, plug in the cable.  Chime plays. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on MacBook Air - MacOS High Sierra

Open Terminal and

```
sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00
```

You’ll be asked to enter your password.

Comment: What does it do? Turn off all sound on a laptop? We do not want all to be OFF

Answer (score 0):

On Mojave you can do the following:

```
ps -eaf | grep Chime
  502 17070     1   0 10:48AM ??         0:00.24 /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/MacOS/PowerChime
  502 17740 16102   0 10:50AM ttys002    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox Chime
```

Find the pid of the powerchime app in this case is **17070**

then do a:

```
kill -9 17070
```

It'll start back up at startup but def kills the process while you're working.