# Stop Macbook from making sound when plugged in to charge

Tags: audio, charging, headphones, sound-volume

I have a Macbook Air and whenever I plug in the USB-C cable to charge, it makes a notification chirp to indicate it's charging.

The problem is that this sound comes out audibly, even when headphones are plugged in (unlike other sounds which do come through the headphones), and even when all sounds are muted (other sounds do get successfully muted).

The charging chirp does not seem to follow regular rules governing notification sound effects. How can I plug my laptop in to charge silently?

Comment: Apple without Steve Jobs is just descending deeper and deeper into suck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit: you may find answers here [Turning Power Chime Off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282752/turning-power-chime-off)

Open Terminal, and run the following command:

`defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnNoHardware -bool true;killall PowerChime`

If that didn't work, try:

`defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool false;killall PowerChime`

To re-enable it:

`defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool true; open /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app &`

Comment: This also persists after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to check it myself, but I found that link here: https://www.iphonetopics.com/enable-power-charging-indicator-sound-mac/

It seems a app called `PowerChime` can do your need.