# How to disable powerchime in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, power

I have found a lot of [post through the internet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282752/turning-power-chime-off) using `com.apple.PowerChime` but I can't find this in Catalina.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this [Github repo](https://github.com/DaFuqtor/powerchime):

> curl -sL git.io/powerchime | sh

Run it to either turn it on or off

Comment: works perfectly. Why is it working while the `com.apple.PowerChime` were not existing first ? (could not see it with completion in terminal)

Comment: @ClementWalter I think it's to do with the file `com.apple.PowerChime` being moved to another location in Catalina

Comment: Dumb question - but is there anyway you can walk me through how to use the github repo?

Am I just typing this into the terminal?

> `curl -sL git.io/powerchime | sh`

Comment: @user3665690 yes, that's right. All you need to do is open up terminal and copy and paste the command.

Comment: This worked for when my laptop is open, but when it is closed, it still chimes (very loud). Is there a way to silence it for plugging it in with the lid closed? (I am using Mac OS 10.15.5 Catalina.)