# How to stop power chime on Monterey with lid closed

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey

I would like to completely disable the power chime on my 2019 MacBook Pro running Monterey (12.3.1). I was able to partially disable it with [git.io/powerchime](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382439/17797), which keeps it from chiming when awake; however, it still chimes if I plug it in when the lid is closed. [Changing defaults](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309947/17797) did not work.

How can I make it so the computer does not chime when closed and USB-C power is connected?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to disable the power chime when the lid is closed is to change audio output to "MacBook Speakers" and turn the system volume down to zero. I'll be eternally grateful if someone finds a better way.